# Fix imperfection on wall (scratches / bumps)

Tags: repair, walls, repainting

Everyone, at some point, start damaging walls.

A chair bump, a scratch and all in between.
I learnt how to make the surface flat again using fillers and then I tried painting carefully using the same paint but...
No joy.
It is always visible that some damage was there.
Paint ages and it is close to impossible to match the same color.

I know that the perfect solution is paint everything again but I'm also curious about some old trick or creative solution to make the wall look nice without painting the whole room.

Comment: Depending on the location of the patch, it is usually much easier to make it a design statement than trying to match and hide.  Most walls are painted one colour, but if there damage that you fix, can maybe paint a strip across the wall in a different colour.

Comment: Wait til you have a whole bunch of imperfections and bang out the whole wall at once?

Comment: For very small patches, ( 1/2 dollar or smaller)  I have found dabbing the paint with a brush rather than strokes removed the possible stroke marks and blended the edges finer.  Larger repairs I use a small roller and then dab the edges.  If the paint is old, either on the wall or in the can there is going to be "scars" no matter what you do.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the great tips! A quesiton @rmdman which is (a very rough) time to consider a paint old?

Comment: @Pitto, in my experience if the paint is 2 years or more on the wall or in the can, you will not get optimal results using it to touch up patches.  That said One may get results that are acceptable because of shadowing,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the main reasons repairs show up is because the wall texture is different between the wall and the repair. Many times, DIYers will sand the repair smooth and then paint. If the wall had any type of texture, even just from a paint roller being used for the original paint job, the repair will stick out like a sore thumb. So try to match the existing texture. Don't paint the repair with a brush. Chances are, the wall was painted with a roller so use that for the repair. Feather the rolling out from the repair to blend in the new paint with the old. This only works if you're using the same paint, same can, as the old paint.

If you have leftover paint, you don't need to paint the whole room, just paint the one wall. You probably won't be able to tell the difference. If you don't have any leftover paint, get a contrasting color and paint the one wall as a accent wall.